# Is this a valid way to show that a Group $G$ is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am working on some elementary problems from group theory. One of them states:

"Suppose for a group $G$, $a^2b^2=(ab)^2$ for all $a,b\in G$. Show that $G$ is abelian."

My process:$$(ab)^2=(ab)(ab)=a^2b^2$$
Since the only way to achieve $a^2b^2$ would be to switch the order of the elements such that $$(ab)(ab)=(ab)(ba)=(a)(b^2)(a)=(a)(a)b^2=a^2b^2$$
we prove that the operation for $G$ is commutative and $G$ is thus abelian.

Is this valid? I do not have much experience in group theory so I am not sure if this is a rigorous/correct way to approach this problem.

Comment: Hint: Existence of an inverse element

Comment: As you've written it, your proof is **not** valid. In writing $(ab)(ab)=(ab)(ba)$, you are assuming the result that you are trying to prove. You are essentially showing "If $G$ is abelian, then $a^2b^2=(ab)^2$ for all $a,b\in G$", which is *not* what you were asked to prove.

Comment: One problem is that you say, without proof, that the **only** way to achieve $a^2b^2$ is a certain switch of the order of $a$ and $b$. Another switch of those elements will also do the job: $(ab)(ab)=a(ba)b=a(ab)b=(aa)(bb)$. How do you know that there isn't some more clever way to do the job without such a switch, or perhaps using two or more such switches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$abab = a^2 b^2$

operate on the left by $a^{-1}$ and on the right by $b^{-1}$

$ba =ab$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is this the standard way to approach verification of abelian groups (via inverses)?

Comment: That every element in the group has an inverse is an important part of the definition of a group and is a tool to have at the ready for many proofs.

Comment: I see, I will definitely keep that in mind.